# java apis for certificate revocation checks

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, certificate

Java supports OCSP out of the box.
The way it is being done though, (I mean the revocation check) is transparent to the programmer.
My question is, is there any api (part of java) that can create a valid OCSP request or response? So that it would be possible for a programmer to implement a custom OCSP checker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Java API does not provide publicly available classes to handle OCSP. In Sun/Oracle's JDK, the OCSP management classes are in the `sun.security.provider.certpath` package (i.e. a package which is outside of the Java specification) and are not `public` (so you cannot use them without resorting to reflection, after giving yourself extended access rights).

Also, the implementation in Sun/Oracle's JDK is a pure client: it can *encode* requests and *decode* responses, but it cannot decode requests or encode responses.

Hence, implementing a custom OCSP checker would entail implementing the encoding and decoding mechanisms manually: it can be done, but not in five lines of code. [EJBCA](http://www.ejbca.org/) is an opensource PKI, entirely written in Java, which includes some support for OCSP (I do not know whether extracting the OCSP code for inclusion in another application would be easy or not).

Comment: +1:This is what I came as a conclusion after looking into it.I will give it a few days and then mark this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Note that Java 8 has a [JEP 124 - Enhance the Certificate Revocation-Checking API](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/124) which should provide new APIs specifically for certificate revocation.

Check out [a recent Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/mullan/entry/jep_124_enhance_the_certificate) describing the new functionality, as well as the [official Draft Readme](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mullan/jeps/124/api/draft.03/README.html).

Hope this helps.