# Java: How to check for certificate revocation given X509TrustManager?

Tags: java, cryptography

Given a candidate certificate chain and a X509TrustManager containing the trusted certificates, how do I check the certificate for revocation? Are Java APIs available to extract and download the CRL, if present, in the CA certificates?

Comment: Duplicated of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362808/java-apis-for-certificate-revocation-checks)?